# Can ELF symbols be represented in UTF8?

Tags: utf-8, elf

May a symbol in the ELF table use UTF8 characters or is it restricted to ASCII?

Note: It is not a problem that I am trying to solve, it is more something I am wondering.

Comment: Not officially… https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tengwar#Unicode ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ELF string tables use NUL-terminated strings, so you could possibly store UTF-8 encoded symbol names inside them.

That said, the tools that use such symbols would need to be Unicode-aware to work correctly.  For example:

- Whether your programming language tool chain correctly classifies a specified Unicode 'character' as a letter, a numeral or punctuation.
- Whether scripts that are written right-to-left (or top-to-bottom) can be used.
- Whether symbols written in complex scripts (Arabic, Thai, etc) are rendered correctly by your system.
- Whether characters from different scripts can be mixed when creating a symbol.
- Whether sorting works as expected, for those tools that have to produce sorted outputs.

... etc.